# Remove added styles with a button

Tags: button, checkbox, styles, addition

I'm trying to have specific styles added to text when a check box is checked and removed when unchecked, which I have managed to figure out, the code isn't pretty, however the results are all that matter.

The problem is however this interferes with another function on my page which is activated with a button, so what I would like is a button function that would remove all the styles that are added.

I've tried various different ways of doing this, one of the closer attempts was:

```
$("#off").click(function(){
  $("p").removeClass("classesadded");
```

});

This simply breaks the previous functions. I think the problem isn't with the way I'm trying to have the button remove the styles, but how the styles are added in the first place. I also tried a function which would uncheck the box on click, which worked but while the box was unchecked the styles remained.

Anyway this is almost impossible to wrap your head around without seeing it so here's a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zwjz2h1x/1/

In short: I want the the checkbox to add/remove the styles and the button to remove styles only if they're already added.

Comment: Can you please tell us what exactly you want ?

Comment: Sorry if it was unclear, I added a summery at the bottom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't u re-use your code u have for the check box?

try this ->

```
$('#toneclass').change(function(){
    toggle(this.checked)
});

function toggle(toggle)
{
    var c = toggle ? 'red' : '';
    $('.high').css('color', c);
    var c = toggle ? 'green' : '';
    $('.mid').css('color', c);
    var c = toggle ? 'yellow' : '';
    $('.low').css('color', c);

    var c = toggle ? 'underline' : '';
    $('.ob').css('text-decoration', c);

    var c = toggle ? '#0000FF' : '';
    $('.ob').css('-moz-text-decoration-color', c);

    var c = toggle ? '#0000FF' : '';
    $('.ob').css('text-decoration-color', c);

    var c = toggle ? '-1px -1px 0 black, 1px -1px 0 black, -1px 1px 0 black,1px 1px 0 black' : '';
    $('.high').css('text-shadow', c);

    var c = toggle ? '-1px -1px 0 black, 1px -1px 0 black, -1px 1px 0 black,1px 1px 0 black' : '';
    $('.mid').css('text-shadow', c);

    var c = toggle ? '-1px -1px 0 black, 1px -1px 0 black, -1px 1px 0 black,1px 1px 0 black' : '';
    $('.low').css('text-shadow', c);
}

//This doesn't work but I wish it did (it breaks the previous code)
//If class on turn off, If not do nothing
$("#off").click(function(){
 toggle(false);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/e2zht5az/1/

Comment: I don't know why I didn't see that. I added:             $(":checkbox").attr("checked", false);
To your code to complete the desired result. Thanks so much.